# Matter with negative mass traveling at the speed of light

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass, speed-of-light

REVISED:
If there was a type of matter that somehow had negative mass that moved towards the speed of light, would time move more quickly for it rather than slowly?

ORIGINAL:
My understanding of dark matter is that it has the opposite effect of gravity, and that as objects accelerate to the speed of light time moves more slowly for them. So as dark matter accelerates to the speed of light does time move more quickly for it? I'm aware that dark matter is supposed to be constant throughout the universe so I don't think it can move in the way normal matter does, but this is a theoretical situation in a science fiction story. If the question doesn't make any sense then perhaps would regular matter that somehow has negative mass have this property?

Comment: A clock has to move faster in its own frame than in any other. Where in the argument for that proposition does it appear to you that an assumption is being made about the mass of that clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense, unfortunately. There're multiple misconceptions:

- Dark matter does NOT have the opposite effect of gravity. That would be dark energy.
- Dark matter behaves like matter. What happens to ordinary matter when they're accelerated near the speed of light also happens to dark matter.
- When matter is moving near the speed of light, time appears to slow down (for the matter). So as dark matter accelerates to the speed of light time does NOT move more quickly for it.
- Dark matter is NOT constant throughout the universe. Again, that would be dark energy.
- Dark matter does NOT have negative mass.
- If instead of dark matter, you're referring to dark energy, then because dark energy is NOT matter, so it cannot accelerate.
- Negative mass would indeed have antigravitational effects, but dark energy cannot be ordinary matter with negative mass, because as far as we can tell it's an intrinsic property of spacetime (for example, there's no reason to suppose that ordinary matter negative mass will be uniformly distributed, but dark energy is).

Comment: Ah you're right I was thinking of dark energy. So if there somehow existed something with the properties of matter but with negative mass (not dark energy) would it have the described reverse relativity effects?

Comment: Are you sure that dark energy is not matter? I think we don't know so much from it until now.

Comment: @peterh I'm certain. In cosmology, matter has a clear definition and so does dark energy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Technical_definition). By definition, dark energy cannot be matter.

Comment: A clock has to move faster in its own frame than in any other.  Where in the argument for that proposition does it appear to you that an assumption is being made about the mass of that clock?

Comment: @WillO I don't understand what you mean (?)

Comment: @Allure:  My apologies.  My comment was intended as a comment on the question, not on your answer.   I'm reposting it in the right place now.